# String to List<object>

Tags: arrays, json, list, flutter, dart

Hello I am new to data management and I have stuck walking these values.

I am using the Hive local storage package, which only allows me to store primitive variables, which is why I converted my service response to a String and stored it in a Box (of Hive).

I need to transform that string, to a List of my objects (List <LanguageModel>), to finally pass it to a widget.

Thanks

This is the transformed string of the objects
[image: This is the string and the objects I am trying to store]

This is the model I use, the toJsonManual () method, it is the one I was trying to use (but it didn't work)
[image: This is the model I use, the toJsonManual () method, it is the one I was trying to use (but it didn't work)]

Answer (score 0):

if i get it right .
you want to store your List as `String`  to save  .
then read it later and convert the `String` to a `List` .
you can do it without any code genration

```
final list = <String,dynamic>[
{'name':'arabic' , 'prefix':'ar'},
{'name':'english' , 'prefix':'en'},
];
```

for simplicity you can use shared preferences to store `List<String>`
just map throw the list and use jsonEncode to conver `Map` to `String`
untill now you can

```
import 'dart:convert';
final data = {'data':list)};
final String encodedData = jsonEncode(data);
```

here you go to convert List to String
my advice is to use the simple option or SQLite  to skip the complexity of decode and encode